# Restrict the input of a textfield in UIAlertController when the user types using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have found this sample code about **how to add the textfield** for the `UIAlertController` **but I am unable to restrict the the users to enter only 10 characters as a limit**, I have a function to remove the last character when it is go over when **editing changed for a regular textfield** but **unable to check the textfield on the `UIAlertController`**.

```
//Function to Remove the last character

func trimStr(existStr:String)->String{

    var countExistTextChar = countElements(existStr)

    if countExistTextChar > 10 {
        var newStr = ""
        newStr = existStr.substringToIndex(advance(existStr.startIndex,(countExistTextChar-1)))
        return newStr

    }else{
        return existStr
    }

}

 var inputTextField: UITextField?

    //Create the AlertController
    let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Swiftly Now! Choose an option!", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    //Create and add the Cancel action
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
        //Do some stuff
    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)
    //Create and an option action
    let nextAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Next", style: .Default) { action -> Void in


    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(nextAction)
    //Add a text field
    **actionSheetController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField -> Void in
        //TextField configuration
        textField.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        inputTextField = textField**


    }

    //Present the AlertController
    self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the *delegate* of the alert controller's text field as
for example showed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24852979/1187415:

```
actionSheetController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { [weak self] textField -> Void in
    //TextField configuration
    textField.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    textField.delegate = self
}
```

Note that you have to add the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol to your
view controller definition to make that compile:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    // ...
```

Then you implement the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate method,
which is called whenever the text is about to be changed in response
to user interaction. It can return `true` or `false` to allow the
change or to deny it.

There are various examples how to limit the text field length in
this delegate method, here is one possible implementation:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
    replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let newString = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string) as NSString
        return newString.length <= 10
}
```

This will cause input to be ignored if it would cause the text field
length to be greater than 10. Alternatively you could always truncate
the input to 10 characters:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
    replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let newString = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
        textField.text = trimStr(newString)
        return false
}
```

A disadvantage of the second method is that the cursor always jumps
to the end of the text field, even if text is inserted somewhere
in between.