# How can I validate a TextField in an .alert?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have added a `TextField` in an `.alert`, which I want to validate. I would like to specify an error text or at least disable the submit button.

I have tried this so far:

```swift
private struct AddButton: View {
    @State private var nameArray = []
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var nameAlreadyExists = false

    var body: some View {
        CustomButton(text: "Add text", action: {
            showAlert = true
        })
        .alert("Add a name", isPresented: $presentSaveRouteAlert, actions: {
            TextField("Name", text: $name)
                .onChange(of: name) { newName in
                    nameAlreadyExists = nameArray.contains(newName)
                }
                
            // Displaying error text not working
            if nameAlreadyExists {
                Text("Name already exists!")
                    .foregroundStyle(.red)
            }
                
            Button("Add", action: {
                nameArray.append(name)
                name = ""
            })
            // Disabling save button not working
            .disabled(nameAlreadyExists)
            
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel, action: {})
        })
    }
}
```

However, it seems to me that changes to the `.alert` are not possible while it is displayed.

Could anyone help me further? [I know that this definitely worked with UIKit.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30596851/14356107)

Comment: What about using a sheet instead?